# Что лучше использовать для git: консольный клиент или графический?

Tags: svn, git, github

Здравствуйте. Перехожу с SVN на GIT. Возник вопрос о том как лучше его использовать через консоль или графический интерфейс? С SVN работал через графический интерфейс т.к. считал, что незачем тратить время на набор команд вручную и да и попахивает это садомазохизмом. Но со временем стало казаться (скорее всего так и есть), что большинство разработчиков используют консоль. Большинство примеров по СВК вроде как через консоль. Почему? Есть какие-то явные преимущества? Или может я все-таки ошибаюсь и удобнее использовать графический интерфейс? В общем помогите пожалуйста определится с выбором.

Answer (score 4):

Комбинирую. Логи и простые коммиты делаю в GUI (TortoiseGit). Перед коммитом в этом же окне можно просмотреть все измененные файлы, просмотреть diff'ы, отметить файлы для коммита и сделать коммит.

Через консоль делаю stash, git add -p и rebase -i. Как-то проще.

Советую попробовать и то, и другое и самому понять как и с помощью чего проще делать.

Answer (score 0):

В консоли конечно же ). Гит в этом попроще, чем SVN. Единственно, что не совсем удобно в терминале, так посмотреть развесистое бранчевание. 
Вообще, у меня текстовом редакторе поддержка гита есть, очень удобно добавлять что то в .gitignore и делать какие то вещи, но основная работа в консоли, там ты неограничен ).

Comment: А в графическом интерфейсе какие ограничения?, которых нет в консоли?
Можно конкретнее пару-тройку весомых преимуществ, если нетрудно?

Comment: Там нету grep’а, мне этого достаточно. Клиенты разные бывают и плагины к ИДЕ, а в консоли один простой и гибкий интерфейс.

Comment: В консоли вы точно сможете использовать __все__ доступные функции git (и любой другой ориентированной на терминал утилиты). В графическом интерфейсе доступный функционал зависит от его разработчика.

Comment: @meboban а как же `git log --graph`? Хотя, наверное, _развесистое_ бранчевание не будет выглядеть лучшим образом. [Ссылка по теме](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git)

Comment: Мне git log --graph хватает, тем более у меня гит может быть на сервере, а там только консоль.
Вообщем нет никакой проблемы в ГУЙовых клиентах, но знать как это делать в консоли очень полезно.

Comment: Ещё хотел добавить про садомазахизм, автор видимо имеет ввиду консоль винды, там конечно же не удобно, на правильных системах такой проблемы нет ;). Часто ловлю себя даже на десктопе, что cd [путь] у меня получается быстрее в *nix системах, чем мышкой.

Comment: @meboban ну консоль винды -- это тоже не так уж плохо. В конце концов command.com давно в могиле. В общем случае консоль позволяет труд автоматизировать. Сделал руками раза два-три, написал скрипт и забыл о проблеме. В гуе мышом надо тыкать постоянно. Так что насчёт садо-мазо -- это ещё надо посмотреть